# free(): invalid next size (normal) while executing free

Tags: c, gnu

I am learning c programming. Below program is showing me the output, But when it execute free method . It is give me error:-  **free(): invalid next size (normal)** . Please let me know what  i am missing.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int main() {

        FILE *fp;

        char r[1024];
        fp = popen("/bin/ls /etc/", "r");

        if (fp == NULL) {
            perror("Failed to run the command");
            exit(-1);
        }

        int totallengthread = 0, alloc_size = 1024;
        char *buffer = (char*) calloc(alloc_size , sizeof(char));
        int lenofbuff = 0;
        while((lenofbuff=fread(r,sizeof(char),1024,fp))>0){

            totallengthread += lenofbuff;
                    if (totallengthread >= alloc_size) {
                        alloc_size += 1024;
                        buffer = realloc(buffer, alloc_size);
                    }
            concat(buffer, r);
        }
        printf("this is the output =>%s", buffer);
        pclose(fp);
        free(buffer);
        return 0;
    }
    void concat(char *dest, const char *source) {
        char *d = dest;
        char *s = source;
        while (*d != '\0') {
            d++;
        }
        while (*s != '\0') {
            *d++ = *s++;
        }
        *d = '\0';
    }
```

Comment: You read up to 1024 bytes and then concatenate it to the buffer. That can easily exceed the size of the buffer. For example, if there are currently 700 bytes in the buffer, and you concatenate 800, you will put 1500 bytes in the buffer. That overflows the buffer and destroys other data in memory. Make sure the buffer is large enough for the data before you put the data in it, not after. Also, be careful about whether your count includes the terminating null character. If you put 1024 non-null characters and a terminating null character into a 1024-byte buffer, you have overrun it.

Comment: eric Postoischil. I am check the size and using realloc extending the size.  It is throwing this error randomly.

Comment: You changed the code in the question. Now it is a different question.

Comment: @Vipin have you tried running this under valgrind and/or address sanitizer?

Comment: Eric Postpischil  Yes you are correct i updated the code. Even in both the case it throws the same error. It was  by mistake from my side while pasting the code.

Comment: `alloc_size += 1024;` won't be enough if more than 1024 bytes were read.

Comment: weather Vane, I am specifying the fread method how much byte to read. Please correct me , if i am wrong. Now i tried to debug again i am finding it is throwing error in free method.

Comment: Yes that's true, but there is still a problem with nul-terminators. There are *probably* no zero terminators in the input, so you can't check for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In modern C, routines must be declared before they are used. Either move the definition of `concat` before main or insert a declaration of `concat` before `main`.
2. Change `int main()` to `int main(void)`.
3. `fread` does not add a null terminator to the data read. Change `char r[1024];` to `char r[1025];` and, after `fread`, insert `r[lenofbuff] = '\0';` as the first statement inside the `while` body.
4. `if (totallengthread >= alloc_size)` does not account for the null terminator. Change it to `if (totallengthread+1 >= alloc_size`)`.
5. In `concat`, change `char *s = source;` to `const char *s = source;`.
6. Turn on compiler warnings and pay attention to them. They should have warned you about 1 and 5 above.
7. After `char *buffer = (char*) calloc(alloc_size, sizeof(char));`, test `buffer == NULL`. If it is, print an error and exit. Also, a better form for this statement is `char *buffer = calloc(alloc_size, sizeof *buffer);`. Casting the result of `calloc` is not needed in C, and basing the size on the thing being allocated rather than a repetition of the type may be safer if the type is changed in the future.
8. Change `buffer = realloc(buffer, alloc_size);` to `char *temp = realloc(buffer, alloc_size * sizeof *buffer); if (temp == NULL) { print message and exit } else buffer = temp;`.

Comment: Eric Postpischil , Thank you so much, This help me a lot. I am learning c programming. And your comments help me a lot to understand my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Attaching the corrected code suggested by Eric Postpischil. It is working fine now.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void concat(char *dest, const char *source);
int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char r[1024];
    fp = popen("/bin/ls /etc/", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to run the command");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int totallengthread = 0, alloc_size = 1024;
    char *buffer = (char*) calloc(alloc_size, sizeof(char));
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        perror("Failed allocate memory");
        exit(-1);
    }
    int lenofbuff = 0;
    while ((lenofbuff = fread(r, sizeof(char), 1023, fp)) > 0) {
        r[lenofbuff] = '\0';
        totallengthread += lenofbuff;
        if ((totallengthread) >= alloc_size) {
            alloc_size += 1024;
            buffer = realloc(buffer, alloc_size*sizeof(char));
            if (buffer == NULL) {
                perror("Failed to extend  memory");
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
        concat(buffer, r);

    }
    printf("this is the output =>%s", buffer);
    pclose(fp);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
void concat(char *dest, const char *source) {
    char *d = dest;
    const char *s = source;
    while (*d != '\0') {
        d++;
    }
    while (*s != '\0') {
        *d++ = *s++;
    }
    *d = '\0';
}
```